# How can i make all the scene dark/night and spot a light on specific place/area in the scene?

Tags: unity, c#

[image: Light]

I want to light the area of the 5 spheres. All the rest to be dark.
What i have in the Hierarchy is Directional Light.
I'm not sure if i need other lights objects and what to do to make it dark/night environment and how to spot a light on the specific area.

Comment: Have you reviewed the Unity documentation on lighting and [types of lights](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lighting.html)? They literally have a spotlight type, which sounds like exactly what you're describing.

Comment: And then not-use a directional light because its equivalent to the sun. And as everyone knows, the sun is not out at night.

Comment: You should consider using a night skybox instead of just rotating the directional light 90 degrees on the x,0 on the y and 0 on the z. You should also check out the lighting window: you can find it under Windows->Lighting. It also gives you control on the ambient lighting, you can either choose to bake/not bake the lighting automatically and so on.